# Can I ask Usability of Program Questions?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask how to do a certain function in the Automator app. Is that an appropriate question to ask in AskDifferent?

Answer (score 2):

The Automator subject is entirely on topic.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

As long as it meets the [generic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) quality requirements, it should not be closed since it’s about software Apple ships.